# after upgrade from appium java client 5.04 to 6.0.1 not able to run testngsuite

Tags: testng, appium

Because i was not able to horizontal swipe in 5.0.4 have upgraded to 6.0.1 for touch action, but now it does not even run following is the error

following is the error found here also i have down the same but not able to solve it kindly help
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/963

Suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 3

## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput;
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.writeTo(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:265)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:175)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>   at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
>   at
> io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:93)
>   at generic.android.BaseSetup.initDriver(BaseSetup.java:86)  at
> generic.android.BaseSetup.setup(BaseSetup.java:43)    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>   at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
>   at
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
> org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
> org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
> org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
> org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
> org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
> org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>   at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>   Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Incomplete document        at
> com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.close(JsonWriter.java:559)      at
> org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.close(JsonOutput.java:39)         at
> io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.writeTo(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:288)
>       ... 41 more
```

Comment: can anyone give some solution ...thanks   appium:1.7.2 selenium-java:3.12 java client : 6.1.0 testng :6.14.2

Comment: i downgraded to 6.0.0 beta and added capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", ".activities.MainActivity"); it worked for me....hope it helps...thanks